Scraping class for ask prices: retrieving incomplete ask-light values
here's my problem. I'm attempting to retrieve various values (prices) from the Binance website. I've managed to extract different classes from the 'orderbook-list-container'. However, it doesn't give me all the ask-light values in this part of the HTML.
Thus, I tried to traverse the different 'div' elements to reach the one I want. Here's what I did:
driver.get("https://www.binance.com/fr/trade/ETH_USDT")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-reject-all-handler"]'))).click()
sleep(0.5)
sell = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="spotOrderbook"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div//div//div//div//div')))
e=0
print(len(sell))
for prix, row in enumerate(sell):
    e+=1
    prixx = sell[prix].get_attribute('ask-light')
    print("Prix pour sell: ", prixx, e)

Everything works; however, I'm unable to retrieve all the 'ask-light' values. So, I'm asking if there's a possibility to get all of them?
Best regards.
Sorry, my translation was not accurate in English; I don't speak the language very well.

Is there any reason you can't use an official API or its python bindings https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ to get the prices you need? In general, scraping should be a last resort if there is no other way to get the info you need.

After several researches, the binance API is not always precise and above all I want to become an expert in the field of web-scraping. Thank you as well as for your help!

The 'ask-light' you are referring to is a class, not an attribute, e.g.
<div class="ask-light" style="font-size: 12px; flex: 1 1 0%; text-align: left;">3070.81</div>

The easiest way to grab all of these is to use a simple CSS selector,
div.ask-light
^ find a DIV tag
   ^ that has a class 'ask-light'

Updating your code, we get
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://www.binance.com/fr/trade/ETH_USDT"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
prices = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ask-light")))
print(len(prices))
for price in prices:
    print(price.text)

driver.quit()

Output
17
3067.51
3067.50
3067.49
3067.48
3067.46
3067.45
3067.41
3067.40
3067.39
3067.36
3067.35
3067.34
3067.33
3067.31
3067.30
3067.29
3067.28
3067.26

